# Dimension too large message when graphing hyperbolic tangent

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to graph hyperbolic tangent but I keep getting the message "Dimension too large" when the parameter "\A" gets too large like .6 or beyond. My code works fine for "\A" equal to .5 or lower (or slightly above .5 like .51), so the code seems fine I think.

Thanks for any help!

Here's the code I'm trying to get to work:

```
\documentclass[border=0mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture} 
 
\def\A{.6}       
\def\b(#1){1+tanh(\A*\x)} 

\draw [samples=100, domain=-9:20] plot ( {\x}, {\b(\x)} );

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you use `pgfplots` then there is no problem. You load the package and you add it as a tag, but you do not use it. http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html

Comment: I agree with @hpekristiansen but if you really need to use Ti*k*Z only you can use `\draw [samples=101, domain=-9:20,
/pgf/fpu/install only=tanh] plot ( {\x}, {\b(\x)} );`. BTW, the definition `\def\b(#1){1+tanh(\A*\x)} ` does not make too much sense since you do not use `#1` in the definition. You could just work with `declare function`.

Comment: @user238301 Thank you, I would rather use TikZ only if possible. I copied and pasted your code but I get and error "Package pgfkeys Error: Choice 'default' unknown in choice key '/pgf/fpu'. I am going to ignore this key." Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Then you most likely have an older TeX installation. If you have a chance, could you try to update it? I believe that the error will then go away.

Comment: You are right! Mine as well as Overleaf's TeX installations gave the pgfkeys error, but after updating my local machine, it works perfectly. Again, thank you, everything works wonderfully.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you get it to work:

For removing the x and y axis and desciptions add `axis line style={draw=none},tick style={draw=none},yticklabels={,,},xticklabels={,,}` to the options for the `axis` environment.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture} 
 \begin{axis}[samples=100, domain=-9:20]
    \def\A{.6}       
    \def\b(#1){1+tanh(\A*\x)} 
    
        \addplot{\b(\x)};
        
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]